# JS - Check which function includes specific string

Tags: javascript, html, string

I'm trying to do some parsing on Html content using JS.
I need to find which function includes specific string, for example:

```
currentGroup.__testButtonOnClick = function () {
            if (currentGroup.__testButton) {
                currentGroup.__testButton.removeFromParent();
                currentGroup.__testButton = null;
            }

            window.location.href = 'http://test.com';
        };
```

The output i'm looking for is "__testButtonOnClick" and i would like to avoid manual parsing and instead use some JS API, does anyone know what would be the best way for that?

Comment: So you are trying to get the functions name, or what exactly do you want? Isn't clear to me.

Comment: are you using ES6 by any chance ?

Comment: So you're not just parsing HTML, but then extracting script content from it and parsing *that*? Or...?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa: Why would that matter?

Comment: because ES6 now has a `function.name` property which obviously ... returns the name of the function. [Check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)

Comment: You're trying to "do some parsing on Html content", and you "need to find which function"---but HTML does not contain functions, JS does. What are you trying to accomplish? There is about a 99.9% chance that there's a better way than trying to parse JS. You say you want to find "which function includes specific string", but in the example you give the function does not include `__testButtonOnClick`, but rather is **assigned** to that member of an object. You are looking for that output based on what input?

Comment: hi,
so let me clarify myself, i am trying to load html content to webview in Android. However, before i load it i want to look for a specific string (window.location.href = 'http://test.com';) and write some code that indicates me which function is surrounding it (__testButtonOnClick)

Comment: @rbd Then add your clarification to your post, and maybe show the content of your panels?

Comment: hi,
so actually the content is dynamic and i can show an example but not sure how much it will help:
var callFunctions() {
   currentGroup.__testButtonOnClick = function () {
            if (currentGroup.__testButton) {
                currentGroup.__testButton.removeFromParent();
                currentGroup.__testButton = null;
            }

            window.location.href = 'http://test.com';
        };

    function trimString(string, before) {
      ...
    }
}